# how to deliver html page in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am learning to set up an application in node js using express framework. I am having problem on how to deliver a html page in the ng-view. I would like to know if I am missing any link or any configuration on how to make that html to be delivered into ng-view.

Here is the code

app/routes/routes.js

```
'use strict';

var clientDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../public')

module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })

    app.get('/login', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(clientDir, 'index.html'))
    })
}
```

public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Login Test</title>

<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/routes/routes.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-view>

  </div>
</div>
```

public/routes/routes.js

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource'])

MyApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {controller: LoginCtrl, templateUrl: '../templates/login.html'}) 
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
})
```

public/controllers/LoginCtrl.js

```
'use strict'
function LoginCtrl ($scope) {

}
```

public/templates/login.html

```
<div class="login-panel panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 40%;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="color: #666;">Please Sign In</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br/>
        For admins only, <br/><br/>
        <div class="login-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Login with Google
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MyApp/app.js

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) process.env.NODE_ENV='development'

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
    path = require('path')
    colors = require('colors')
    require("./app/routes/routes")(app)

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening in %s on port %s', colors.red(process.env.NODE_ENV), app.get('port'))

})
```

Folder structure:

```
MyApp
 app
  routes
   routes.js
 bower_components
 node_modules
 public
  index.html
  routes
   routes.js
  controllers
  templates
 app.js
 package.json
```

I am able to deliver an index.html which has an ng-view but I am not able to place login.html page in that view and that is what I am trying for. Please let me know what am i missing here in order to deliver login.html. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include ngRoute in your public/routes/routes.js:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck.. I doubt if loading this <script src="/routes/routes.js"></script> is a problem because I see it getting failed to GET this script in index.html.. Am i giving the path for the routes.js in the right way? I tried may ways to get the script in the right way but it says GET failed.